# Wiktionary in Structured Format

Tags: xml, rdf, semantic-web, wiktionary, wikimedia-dumps

How do I aqcuire a Wiktionary, for say English, in structured format, typically RDF?

The recommended website http://downloads.dbpedia.org/wiktionary/ is dead.

And I don't understand if there are some existing frameworks that extract an RDF-representation from the XML dumps [in the official Wikimedia Foundation dumps](http://dumps.wikimedia.org/backup-index.html).

Do I have to do processing of the XML-dumps myself?

Comment: I think this might be better directed at the mailing list of whoever was supposed to be maintaining the recommended link.

Comment: It also might help to provide a bit more context.  The [Wiktionary RDF extraction](http://wiki.dbpedia.org/wiktionary-rdf-extraction) provides that link (that is now dead), but it also might lead to the right mailing lists or email addresses of people to contact.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [dbnary](http://kaiko.getalp.org/about-dbnary/) project extracts RDF data from Wiktionary.

Answer (score 2):

Another great option is the [Kaikki JSON data.](https://kaikki.org/)